# Common Front door bicep for multiple environment

Tags: azure, azure-bicep, infrastructure-as-code, azure-front-door

I am creating a bicep template for front door and I would like o use it for more than one environment

I have an existing environment but when I call it for another environment it fails That resource name isn't available. (Code: Conflict)

Here is my set up:

main bicep

```
module frontdoorModule 'frontdoor.bicep' = {
 name: ''
 params: {
   frontDoorName: 'devqa'
   endpoints: endpoints
   backendPoolArray: backendPoolArray
   routingRules: routingRules
 }
}
```

Param file - for dev

```
"endpoints": {
      "value": [
        {
          "name": "frontendEndpoint",
          "hostName": "devqa.azurefd.net"
        }
      ]
    },
    "backendPoolArray": {
      "value": [
        {
          "backendPoolName": "devbackendpool",
          "backendAddress": "myappdev.azurewebsites.net"
        }
      ]
    },
    "routingRules": {
      "value": [
        {
          "routingRuleName": "devappruleforrouting",
          "backendPoolName": "devbackendpool",
          "endpointName": "frontendEndpoint"
        }
      ]
    }
```

Param file for QA

```
"endpoints": {
      "value": [
        {
          "name": "frontendEndpoint",
          "hostName": "devqa.azurefd.net"
        }
      ]
    },
    "backendPoolArray": {
      "value": [
        {
          "backendPoolName": "qabackendpool",
          "backendAddress": "myappqa.azurewebsites.net"
        }
      ]
    },
    "routingRules": {
      "value": [
        {
          "routingRuleName": "qaappruleforrouting",
          "backendPoolName": "qabackendpool",
          "endpointName": "frontendEndpoint"
        }
      ]
    }
```

It is a classic front door
frontdoor.bicep

```
resource frontDoorResource 'Microsoft.Network/frontDoors@2021-06-01' = {
  name: frontDoorName
  location: 'global'
  properties: {
    enabledState: 'Enabled'

    frontendEndpoints: [for endpoint in endpoints: {
      name: endpoint.name
      properties: {
        hostName: endpoint.hostName
        sessionAffinityEnabledState: 'Disabled'
      }
    }]

    loadBalancingSettings: [
      {
        name: loadBalancingSettingsName
        properties: {
          sampleSize: 4
          successfulSamplesRequired: 2
        }
      }
    ]

    healthProbeSettings: [
      {
        name: healthProbeSettingsName
        properties: {
          path: '/'
          protocol: 'Http'
          intervalInSeconds: 120
        }
      }
    ]

    backendPools: [for backendPool in backendPoolArray: {
      name: backendPool.backendPoolName
      properties: {
        backends: [
          {
            address: backendPool.backendAddress
            backendHostHeader: backendPool.backendAddress
            httpPort: 80
            httpsPort: 443
            weight: 100
            priority: 1
            enabledState: 'Enabled'
          }
        ]
        loadBalancingSettings: {
          id: resourceId('Microsoft.Network/frontDoors/loadBalancingSettings', frontDoorName, loadBalancingSettingsName)
        }
        healthProbeSettings: {
          id: resourceId('Microsoft.Network/frontDoors/healthProbeSettings', frontDoorName, healthProbeSettingsName)
        }
      }
    }]

    routingRules: [for routingRule in routingRules: {
      name: routingRule.routingRuleName
      properties: {
        frontendEndpoints: [
          {
            id: resourceId('Microsoft.Network/frontDoors/frontEndEndpoints', frontDoorName, routingRule.endpointName)
          }
        ]
        acceptedProtocols: [
          'Http'
          'Https'
        ]
        patternsToMatch: [
          '/*'
        ]
        routeConfiguration: {
          '@odata.type': '#Microsoft.Azure.FrontDoor.Models.FrontdoorForwardingConfiguration'
          forwardingProtocol: 'MatchRequest'
          backendPool: {
            id: resourceId('Microsoft.Network/frontDoors/backEndPools', frontDoorName, routingRule.backendPoolName)
          }
        }
        enabledState: 'Enabled'
      }
    }]
  }
}
```

When I added the second param file and made it run I got the error "That resource name isn't available. (Code: Conflict)"

Comment: which resource group are you deploying your front door? are you targeting the same resource group when deploying your bicep in dev and qa ?

Comment: I am targeting different resource groups

Comment: if you change the resource group name for front door, it will try to create a new one hence the error message.

Comment: So you mean there is no way that I can  have the following set up: RG1 has app service and front door, RG2 has app service and refers to existing front door in RG1?

Comment: The whole reason for doing this is having to avoid paying the cost for an additional front door instance as rules are inexpensive

Comment: What if I force the RG value for front door module point to the existing one?

Comment: yeah that will work. the scope of the front door module needs to be RG1 in both case

Comment: I do not see a parameter to force resource group name, can you please help?

Comment: when you deploy the module you can specify the scope: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/bicep/bicep-functions-scope#resource-group-example

Comment: so for you `scope: resourceGroup('RG1')`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255311/discussion-between-lucky-and-thomas).

Comment: I did try this, the issue I am facing by forcing the scope to dev rg is that the older routing rule and backendpool go overridden. The dev details got replaced with the backend pool and routing rule details that were sent as part of the param file for qa environment.