# Standard Front door bicep / parent child bicep relation

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-bicep, infrastructure-as-code, azure-front-door

I need to know if there is a way to refer an existing resource as parent by a different module or resource and not override the existing set up.

Here is an example:

I have a front door (standard) bicep being called as a module.
In Environment 1: I have 2 web apps and are hosted in 2 app services (web app 1 in appservice1 and web app 2 in appservice2). I will use the above front door and I will create two origin groups (one each with one app service), two end points and two route.

In Environment 2: I have similar setup but I want to use the existing front door from Environment 1.

How should I set up my bicep files and use as modules? I need parameter file for each environment. The origin group, end point has parent child relation ship. I am not finding a way to deal with it?

Reason: Have one instance of front door standard to save in base cost.

Edit 1:
Adding bicep: Need to call this as module for multiple non production environments. Finally, there should be one front door with multiple front end c(custom), backend pools and routing rules (in case of classic) or multiple origin group/origin, endpoint/route (in case of standard)

```
param location string = resourceGroup().location

param appName string = 'myapp-${uniqueString(resourceGroup().id)}'

param appServicePlanSkuName string = 'S1'

param appServicePlanCapacity int = 1

param frontDoorEndpointName string = 'afd-${uniqueString(resourceGroup().id)}'

@allowed([
  'Standard_AzureFrontDoor'
  'Premium_AzureFrontDoor'
])
param frontDoorSkuName string = 'Standard_AzureFrontDoor'

var appServicePlanName = 'AppServicePlan'

var frontDoorProfileName = 'MyFrontDoor'
var frontDoorOriginGroupName = 'MyOriginGroup'
var frontDoorOriginName = 'MyAppServiceOrigin'
var frontDoorRouteName = 'MyRoute'

resource frontDoorProfile 'Microsoft.Cdn/profiles@2021-06-01' = {
  name: frontDoorProfileName
  location: 'global'
  sku: {
    name: frontDoorSkuName
  }
}

resource appServicePlan 'Microsoft.Web/serverFarms@2020-06-01' = {
  name: appServicePlanName
  location: location
  sku: {
    name: appServicePlanSkuName
    capacity: appServicePlanCapacity
  }
  kind: 'app'
}

resource app 'Microsoft.Web/sites@2020-06-01' = {
  name: appName
  location: location
  kind: 'app'
  identity: {
    type: 'SystemAssigned'
  }
  properties: {
    serverFarmId: appServicePlan.id
    httpsOnly: true
    siteConfig: {
      detailedErrorLoggingEnabled: true
      httpLoggingEnabled: true
      requestTracingEnabled: true
      ftpsState: 'Disabled'
      minTlsVersion: '1.2'
      ipSecurityRestrictions: [
        {
          tag: 'ServiceTag'
          ipAddress: 'AzureFrontDoor.Backend'
          action: 'Allow'
          priority: 100
          headers: {
            'x-azure-fdid': [
              frontDoorProfile.properties.frontDoorId
            ]
          }
          name: 'Allow traffic from Front Door'
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}

resource frontDoorEndpoint 'Microsoft.Cdn/profiles/afdEndpoints@2021-06-01' = {
  name: frontDoorEndpointName
  parent: frontDoorProfile
  location: 'global'
  properties: {
    enabledState: 'Enabled'
  }
}

resource frontDoorOriginGroup 'Microsoft.Cdn/profiles/originGroups@2021-06-01' = {
  name: frontDoorOriginGroupName
  parent: frontDoorProfile
  properties: {
    loadBalancingSettings: {
      sampleSize: 4
      successfulSamplesRequired: 3
    }
    healthProbeSettings: {
      probePath: '/'
      probeRequestType: 'HEAD'
      probeProtocol: 'Http'
      probeIntervalInSeconds: 100
    }
  }
}

resource frontDoorOrigin 'Microsoft.Cdn/profiles/originGroups/origins@2021-06-01' = {
  name: frontDoorOriginName
  parent: frontDoorOriginGroup
  properties: {
    hostName: app.properties.defaultHostName
    httpPort: 80
    httpsPort: 443
    originHostHeader: app.properties.defaultHostName
    priority: 1
    weight: 1000
  }
}

resource frontDoorRoute 'Microsoft.Cdn/profiles/afdEndpoints/routes@2021-06-01' = {
  name: frontDoorRouteName
  parent: frontDoorEndpoint
  dependsOn: [
    frontDoorOrigin // This explicit dependency is required to ensure that the origin group is not empty when the route is created.
  ]
  properties: {
    originGroup: {
      id: frontDoorOriginGroup.id
    }
    supportedProtocols: [
      'Http'
      'Https'
    ]
    patternsToMatch: [
      '/*'
    ]
    forwardingProtocol: 'HttpsOnly'
    linkToDefaultDomain: 'Enabled'
    httpsRedirect: 'Enabled'
  }
}

output appServiceHostName string = app.properties.defaultHostName
output frontDoorEndpointHostName string = frontDoorEndpoint.properties.hostName
```

Edit 26Sep
The bicep with iterative loop

```
resource frontDoorProfile 'Microsoft.Cdn/profiles@2021-06-01' existing = {
  name: frontDoorProfileName
}

resource frontDoorEndpointArray 'Microsoft.Cdn/profiles/afdEndpoints@2021-06-01' = [for item in endPointNames:{
  parent: frontDoorProfile
  name: '${item}'
  location: 'global'
  properties: {
    enabledState: 'Enabled'
  }
}]

resource frontDoorOriginGroupArray 'Microsoft.Cdn/profiles/originGroups@2021-06-01' = [for item in originGroupNames:{
  parent: frontDoorProfile
  name: '${item}'
  properties: {
    loadBalancingSettings: {
      sampleSize: 4
      successfulSamplesRequired: 3
      additionalLatencyInMilliseconds: 50
    }
    healthProbeSettings: {
      probePath: '/'
      probeRequestType: 'HEAD'
      probeProtocol: 'Https'
      probeIntervalInSeconds: 100
    }
    sessionAffinityState: 'Disabled'
  }
}]
```

frontDoorOrigin and frontDoorRoute - I am stuck with as their parent are frontDoorOriginGroup and frontDoorEndpoint but they are multiple.

Comment: Have you tried any code so far? @Lucky

Comment: you need to put the common front door part in a separated module then that should work

Comment: I was trying to, the moment I get stuck is I create the front door profile as a resource, origin with fdprofile as parent, front door end point with parent etc. And then I am failing to understand how the parent relation will be established when the next environment run, as it needs to refer to the existing front door profile and add just the environment specific end point/route, origin group/origin to it.

Comment: Also when in the future this front door will have multiple origin group, end points, and it is being run for development environment it should persist the other environments like test and uat with old set up and not lose it.

Comment: @Thomas Sorry I do not understand what do you mean when you say common. If I am calling front door standard bicep as module, the bice file has front door profile, origin group which refers profile as parents so on and so forth.

Comment: I am adding a bicep for example in the question so it becomes easier to talk about and refer. And lets assume I need to call this as a module in main for Dev, Test, Acceptance i.e. all non production environements. The bicep added is for standard only not for classic, please let me know if required I can add)

Comment: everything is in one module. if your front door and app services are not is the same resource group that wont work cause a deployment is tied to to a resource group

Comment: AFAIK, to refer the existing resource as a parent without disturbing the existing set up, you can `parent` property in the child resource after defining an existing resource with the `existing` keyword. And after that if you want to use the `frontdoorprofilename` in multiple `nonproduction` environments, you can pass the name of the front door resource as a parameter to the module under `params` block. Did you try that way? @Lucky

Comment: @Jahnavi: Let's say I have a bicep for frontdoorprofile and I use it to create the profile for the first time. I cannot introduce existing keyword when I run it for next environment, right? Or can I?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're referencing this existing [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77112218/common-front-door-bicep-for-multiple-environment) where you have two environments:

- env1 is in rg1 (Front door is located in rg1)
- env2 is in rg2

The problem is that the webapp and front door may not be in the same resource group and a module is tied to a resource group.
You will need to split your bicep file into different modules.

Here I have:

- a front door module that just create the front door profile
- a webapp module that create the webapp
- a front door webapp module to configure the webapp inside front door:

front-door.bicep module:

```
param frontDoorProfileName string
param frontDoorSkuName string = 'Standard_AzureFrontDoor'

output name string = frontDoorProfile.name
output frontDoorId string = frontDoorProfile.properties.frontDoorId

resource frontDoorProfile 'Microsoft.Cdn/profiles@2021-06-01' = {
  name: frontDoorProfileName
  location: 'global'
  sku: {
    name: frontDoorSkuName
  }
}
```

webapp.bicep module:

```
param location string = resourceGroup().location
param appName string
param appServicePlanName string = '${appName}-asp'
param appServicePlanSkuName string = 'S1'
param appServicePlanCapacity int = 1
param frontDoorId string

output name string = app.name
output defaultHostName string = app.properties.defaultHostName

resource appServicePlan 'Microsoft.Web/serverfarms@2022-09-01' = {
  name: appServicePlanName
  location: location
  sku: {
    name: appServicePlanSkuName
    capacity: appServicePlanCapacity
  }
  kind: 'app'
}

resource app 'Microsoft.Web/sites@2020-06-01' = {
  name: appName
  location: location
  kind: 'app'
  identity: {
    type: 'SystemAssigned'
  }
  properties: {
    serverFarmId: appServicePlan.id
    httpsOnly: true
    siteConfig: {
      detailedErrorLoggingEnabled: true
      httpLoggingEnabled: true
      requestTracingEnabled: true
      ftpsState: 'Disabled'
      minTlsVersion: '1.2'
      ipSecurityRestrictions: [
        {
          tag: 'ServiceTag'
          ipAddress: 'AzureFrontDoor.Backend'
          action: 'Allow'
          priority: 100
          headers: {
            'x-azure-fdid': [
              frontDoorId
            ]
          }
          name: 'Allow traffic from Front Door'
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

front-door-webapp.bicep module:

```
param frontDoorProfileName string
param frontDoorEndpointName string
param frontDoorOriginGroupName string
param frontDoorOriginName string
param frontDoorOriginHostName string
param frontDoorRouteName string

// Get a reference to the existing front door profile
resource frontDoorProfile 'Microsoft.Cdn/profiles@2021-06-01' existing = {
  name: frontDoorProfileName
}

// Create an endpoint (frontend)
resource frontDoorEndpoint 'Microsoft.Cdn/profiles/afdEndpoints@2021-06-01' = {
  name: frontDoorEndpointName
  parent: frontDoorProfile
  location: 'global'
  properties: {
    enabledState: 'Enabled'
  }
}

// Create an origin group (backend pool)
resource frontDoorOriginGroup 'Microsoft.Cdn/profiles/originGroups@2021-06-01' = {
  name: frontDoorOriginGroupName
  parent: frontDoorProfile
  properties: {
    loadBalancingSettings: {
      sampleSize: 4
      successfulSamplesRequired: 3
      additionalLatencyInMilliseconds: 50
    }
    healthProbeSettings: {
      probePath: '/'
      probeRequestType: 'HEAD'
      probeProtocol: 'Https'
      probeIntervalInSeconds: 100
    }
  }
}

// Create an origin (backend inside a backend pool)
resource frontDoorOrigin 'Microsoft.Cdn/profiles/originGroups/origins@2021-06-01' = {
  name: frontDoorOriginName
  parent: frontDoorOriginGroup
  properties: {
    hostName: frontDoorOriginHostName
    httpPort: 80
    httpsPort: 443
    originHostHeader: frontDoorOriginHostName
    priority: 1
    weight: 1000
    enforceCertificateNameCheck: true
  }
}

// Create a route (routing rule: mapping an endpoint to an origin group)
resource frontDoorRoute 'Microsoft.Cdn/profiles/afdEndpoints/routes@2021-06-01' = {
  name: frontDoorRouteName
  parent: frontDoorEndpoint
  dependsOn: [
    frontDoorOrigin // This explicit dependency is required to ensure that the origin group is not empty when the route is created.
  ]
  properties: {
    originGroup: {
      id: frontDoorOriginGroup.id
    }
    supportedProtocols: [
      'Http'
      'Https'
    ]
    patternsToMatch: [
      '/*'
    ]
    forwardingProtocol: 'HttpsOnly'
    linkToDefaultDomain: 'Enabled'
    httpsRedirect: 'Enabled'
  }
}
```

And from your main.bicep, you can orchestrate the creation of the different resources. Note that I have a parameter for the front door resource group name (when front door is not created in the same resource group as the webapp):

```
param location string = resourceGroup().location

param frontDoorProfileResourceGroupName string = 'thomastest-rg1'
param frontDoorProfileName string = 'thomastest-fd'
param webappName string = 'thomastest-wapp1'

// Create front door profile
module frontdoorProfile 'front-door.bicep' = {
  name: frontDoorProfileName
  // Front door may not be in the same resource group as the webapp
  scope: resourceGroup(frontDoorProfileResourceGroupName)
  params: {
    frontDoorProfileName: frontDoorProfileName
  }
}

// Create the webapp
module webapp 'webapp.bicep' = {
  name: webappName
  params: {
    location: location
    appName: webappName
    frontDoorId: frontdoorProfile.outputs.frontDoorId
  }
}

// Configure front door
module frontdoorWebApp 'front-door-webapp.bicep' = {
  name: 'fd-${webappName}'
  // Front door may not be in the same resource group as the webapp
  scope: resourceGroup(frontDoorProfileResourceGroupName)
  params: {
    frontDoorProfileName: frontdoorProfile.outputs.name
    frontDoorEndpointName: webapp.outputs.name
    frontDoorOriginGroupName: webapp.outputs.name
    frontDoorOriginHostName: webapp.outputs.defaultHostName
    frontDoorOriginName: webapp.outputs.name    
    frontDoorRouteName: webapp.outputs.name
  }
}
```

Comment: I will give it a try but something like this is not possible in classic I presume, am I right?

Comment: not the same way for sure

Comment: What happens if there are multiple origins, routes, end points. In case of front-door-webapp.bicep module: if there are multiple frontDoorOriginGroup (array) then how do I refer individual entry of that as parent in frontDoorOrigin similarly in frontdoor route as well

Comment: Did it work for you? You could always use loop to iterate https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/bicep/loops. Feel free to post an ew question if needed.

Comment: I have added the bicep and where I am facing a challenge in loop in my question, please if you can take a look